# preg_replace to change image path

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to replace in a php file some text from DB with `preg_replace`. The string to replace is:

```
images/
```

and change it to

```
cms/images/
```

I know it's simple but I just can't understand this syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the OP requested a solution using `preg_replace()` here's one. Otherwise the solution of @genesis is more than suitable.

`$new_string = preg_replace('#images/#i', 'cms/images/', $string);`

The above simply replaces `images/` with `cms/images/` in `$string`. The # symbols are delimiters which separate the expression from the modifiers. In this case the `images/` and `i` respectively. The `i` makes it case insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

```
$new_string = str_replace('images/', 'cms/images/', $string);
```

Comment: You probably want a slash after cms/images. i.e. `cms/images/`. Otherwise, +1.

Comment: @Herbert: correct. I have added this. Thanks for your warning